# Best way to draw a large number of circles on Android?

Tags: android, performance, canvas, gpu

I'm creating an application on android, in some part I have to draw a lot of small circles to represent a type of data. My datasets has about 20000 points, and the delay to handle (translation and scale) this data is too bad to user experience and it cannot be this way. I'm using a Fragment and drawning those points with Canvas for Android SDK. Anybody have other ideas to draw a large amount of points that costs less and maybe translation and scale won't be a problem anymore?

Comment: SurfaceView with OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you

1. draw one circle to a separate canvas;
2. convert this to an alpha-blended bitmap;
3. draw all your circles by rendering this bitmap.

This will avoid the processing that goes into each step by which Android has to render the circle as a bitmap.

Beyond that, you might try to work out whether you really need all your data points. It is hard to believe that 20,000 circles will be more meaningful to the user than some aggregated or approximated view.

Comment: Also, you can draw the circles to a bitmap buffer as to not draw them every frame, and only refreshes it when the user does something to change the content.

Comment: After doind that I could put on click listener events on those points? The points has diferent colors it would be a problem?